# How to find contract change by reverse engenering bytecode changes?

Tags: solidity, bytecode, decompilers

A while ago I deployed a smart contract, which has not been verified. Since then I have created a few newer versions, so the original one got lost in commits.

My question is using bytecode comparison, **what would be the easiest way to find the part of code that has been changed**, without comparing every version? Beware that the contract is pretty long so decompiling every command would take ages.